# Docker-compose failed to read Dockerfile

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose

I am having a strange issue with compose since yesterday (01.12.), where my docker-compose can't read the Dockerfile. The issue appeared out of the blue because the code hasn't changed but the build started to fail.

My docker-compose:

```
service1:
image: service1-image
build:
  context: ${SERVICE1_DIR}
  dockerfile: \src\Service1.Service\Service1.Service.Web\Dockerfile-Development
ports:
  - "${HTTP_SERVICE1_PORT}:80"
  - "${HTTPS_SERVICE1_PORT}:443"
environment:
  - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
  - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+
  - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=${HTTPS_SERVICE1_PORT}
  - ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings__SQLServer=Server=sqlserver;Database=Service1;User ID=sa;Password=****
  - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=${CERT_PASSWORD}
  - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=${SERVICE1_CERT_PATH}
volumes:
  - ${DOCKER_DIR}\https:/https/:ro
```

There is no issue with the Dockerfile-Development itself because I am able to build the image directly by using **docker build** command. Also, if I change it to Dockerfile the error is the same.

> SERVICE1_DIR is the path to the root of the folder (solution) and then
> I am extending the path to dockerfile which is located where my Web
> API project is. There are a couple of Class Library project on which
> my API has a dependency on. All of which I am referencing in my
> dockerfile without any issue.

My environment:

- docker-compose file version: 3.4
- docker version: Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396

I am using .NET SDK 6.0 and ASPNET 6.0 runtime.

Here is the error:

```
 => ERROR [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-Development                                             
 0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 79B                                                                                
 0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  
 0.1s
 => => transferring context: 35B                                                                                   
 0.0s
 ------
 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-Development:
 ------
 failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from 
 sender: resolve : CreateFile \\?\C:\src: The system cannot find the file specified.
 ERROR: Service 'service1' failed to build : Build failed
```

** **UPDATE WITH SOLUTION** **

Resolved the issue with adding the missing part of the path to **dockerfile** in **build**

Working docker-compose file:

```
service1:
    image: service1-image
    build:
      context: ${SERVICE1_DIR}
      dockerfile: ${SERVICE1_DIR}\src\Service1.Service\Service1.Service.Web\Dockerfile-Development
    ports:
      - "${HTTP_SERVICE1_PORT}:80"
      - "${HTTPS_SERVICE1_PORT}:443"
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+;http://+
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=${HTTPS_SERVICE1_PORT}
      - ASPNETCORE_ConnectionStrings__SQLServer=Server=sqlserver;Database=Service1;User ID=sa;Password=****
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=${CERT_PASSWORD}
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=${SERVICE1_CERT_PATH}
    volumes:
      - ${DOCKER_DIR}\https:/https/:ro
```

Comment: Well if it isn't the docker-compose file, this question is pretty much off-topic for Stack Overflow. It's somewhere in the environment then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your docker-compose.yaml you have `dockerfile` with `\src\Service1.Service\Service1.Service.Web\Dockerfile-Development` which is an absolute path that Windows has resolved to `C:\src...`. Unless you have your application in this directory, your `dockerfile` path in docker-compose.yaml is incorrect and should be relative to the docker-compose.yaml. Likely `${SERVICE1_DIR}\Service1.Service.Web\Dockerfile-Development` or similar.

Comment: Thank you this actually did the trick. It didn't cross my mind to actually check the path because this code stopped working without any changes to the path or dockerfile location inside the project. I will update the question with the solution and will give +1!